# how to find which part of joomla is slowing down my system?

Tags: mysql, joomla

I've this slow query in mysql :

```
Count: 59  Time=14.19s (837s)  Lock=0.00s (0s)  Rows=1.5 (87), fmrh[fmrh]@localhost
  SELECT DISTINCT v.id
  FROM jos_custom_properties_fields AS f
  INNER JOIN jos_custom_properties_values as v
  LEFT JOIN jos_jf_content AS jfcf ON jfcf.reference_id = f.id
  LEFT JOIN jos_languages as jflf ON jfcf.language_id = jflf.id
  LEFT JOIN jos_jf_content AS jfcv ON jfcv.reference_id = v.id
  LEFT JOIN jos_languages as jflv ON jfcv.language_id = jflv.id
  WHERE f.access <= 'S'
  AND ( (jfcf.value = 'S' AND jflf.code = 'S')
  OR f.label = 'S'  )
  AND ( (jfcv.value = 'S' AND jflv.code = 'S')
  OR v.label = 'S' )
```

but I don't where in the joomla it's used.
It's a single hosting that slows down a 4 core VMachine whith only 2 users.
The developper/integrator is not available any more, and I don't know what I can do to detect the joomla-extension that is making this happen. I think it's joomla-fish but I'm not sure.

**jfcf.value = 'S'** makes a search among a MEDIUM TEXT field in a table with 60Mb, I think this is not wright.

Thank you in advance for your time.

Vicente

Answer (score 0):

create an index for the value column in jos_jf_content table, the execution speed will increase

Comment: Can I create an index on a MEDIUM TEXT field?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems that there's a problem with some "custom_properties". There was no benefit on creating the index on the field.

We work with mysql 5.0.29